# How To make Bulk email Script using php

Tags: php, email

I am making a bulk email script for 1k user and I want to send email but my script gives me error, timeout.

How to handle page timeout. any suggestion for backend run this script.

If user clicks send button then run this script backend if user close this page but script working.

```
    $Email_ID="";
    $queryUser=mysql_query("SELECT  `email` From `users`",$conn);
    while($User=mysql_fetch_array($queryUser))
    {
        $to = $User["email"];
        $Email_ID=$User["email"];
        $from = 'donotreply@abc.com';
        $from_name = 'Test bulk email';
        $senderMail="donotreply@abc.com";
        $senderName="abc";
        $message=$_POST["message"];
        $subject = $_POST["subject"]; 
        $html_content = $_POST["message"];
        $from = $senderName." <".$senderMail.">"; 
        $headers = "From: $from";
        $headers = "CC: jignesh.tplabs@gmail.com";
        $headers = "BCC: jignesh.tplabs@gmail.com";

        $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

        $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

        $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 

        $upload_file="";
        if(isset($_SESSION["uniqid"]))
        {
            $query=mysql_query("SELECT  * From `bulk_email_attchment` where `unique_id`='".$_SESSION["uniqid"]."' ",$conn);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {
                        $files = "Attchment/".$row["name"];
                        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                        $fp =    @fopen($files,"rb");
                        $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($files));
                        @fclose($fp);
                        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($files)."\"\n" . 
                        "Content-Description: ".basename($files)."\n" .
                        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($files)."\"; size=".filesize($files).";\n" . 
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                }
        }


        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
        $returnpath = "-f" . $senderMail;

        //send email
        $mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Argh, please don't use the `@` operator for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a cron script. So your email script handled by cron and run in background.

Comment: any time limit cron execution? like webpage 30 sec

Answer (score 1):

**The Right Way:** Create a php Queue, with a Named Pipe, that connects to another php script that would send the emails each time it is invoked. If you are just staring php, it'll take a while before all this is coded properly.

**The Moderate but not ideal way:** Set up a Cron Job to invoke your script (that would send 20 or so emails each time invoked. If your using a service like Godaddy, just google: "CronJob godaddy setup"

**The Hacky Way:** Have the script in a page that redirects to itself with a query string updating it on how many emails were sent:

After 20 emails for instance are sent, use the code:

```
$count = 20;
header('Location http://www.example.com/index.php?count='.$count);
```

I don't recommend using The Hacky Way because as a programmer, we should try to follow best practices, but I personally can't hold you back :)

Comment: thank you. temporary  i use cron job.  any time limit for cron job execution. ??

Comment: @user3496831 When you set up a cron job on Godaddy's CPanel, or any other control panel provided by a hosting provider, there will be sections which provide options regarding how many times you want the script to be executed. You could easily place it once per day, once per hour, once per 5 seconds! Oh and if this answer is the one that worked for you, please accept it with a green check mark so that future users know it worked for you :)

Comment: @user3496831 Depends on how long it takes to send 20 emails or whichever amount you are sending. If it takes 10 seconds, maybe 12 seconds per con job call just to be safe, though more or less shouldn't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

If you want to continue a script if the user aborts you can use `ignore_user_abort()`.

```
// Ignore if a user aborts
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

// Send your emails here
```

For more information check the PHP `ignore_user_abort()` (documentation)[http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ignore-user-abort.php]

#### Option 2

Insert all submited form data into a database. You can then make a cron job that checks if there are new email jobs to submit and submit them. This way the user won't have to wait and you will not have the problem of them closing the browser.